# html5 input type="number" doesn't work with ng-model="selectedItem.price" in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html

why does angular model doesn't work with the input type number? but works in input type text.

here's my code

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" name="price" ng-model="selectedItem.price" autocomplete="off">
```

Here's the solution.. in my database the data type is decimal not string..  but angularjs make it to string after it gets the data.. so I add "+" to convert it to int again.

```
$scope.selectedItem={ item_id:"", item_name:"",supplier:"",price:"",description:"" };

<input type="number" step="0.01" name="price" ng-model="+selectedItem.price" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: What is that **step**? What value passing in **ng-model**?

Comment: to set the format decimal in input element

Comment: What value passing in ng-model? i think in **selectedItem.price** u r passing string... Can you check the data type of ng-model.. if u r passing **selectedItem.price=="2"** like this it won't work. Need to pass Integer value Only.

Comment: thanks, i found out the problem :)

Comment: I add "+" in the ng-model to convert it to string...<input type="number" step="0.01" name="price" id="email" ng-model="+selectedProduct.price" autocomplete="off"> and it displays value now :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Example - example-number-input-directive-production</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="numberExample">
        <script>
            angular.module('numberExample', [])
                    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {    
                    $scope.selectedItem = {
                        price: 2.5
                    };
                }]);
        </script>
        <form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">

            <input type="number" step="0.01" name="price" ng-model="selectedItem.price" autocomplete="off">   
            <tt>value = {{selectedItem.price}}</tt><br/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: but it doesn't display value in the input element

Comment: did you try my code with an individual file.  ??  
i have made fresh file. and its working..

Comment: you might missing some controller name or something, without checking your JS code we can not judge., that is why i have created a fresh file and showed you that your HTML part is correct, but issue might be there in you JS code or syntax.

Comment: i have edited the code., check it now and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think in **selectedItem.price** u r passing string... Can you check the data type of ng-model.. if u r passing

```
  $scope.selectedItem={
    price="2" 
 };
```

like above it won't work. Need to pass Integer value Only. Like below means, it will work.

```
$scope.selectedItem={
 price:2;
}
```

Convert to string to Integer.

Comment: this is what i have... $scope.selectedProduct={ product_id:"", product_name:"",supplier:"",price:"",description:"" }; if i remove the quote the code will not work so, what i did is,  i just put "+" in selectedItem.price to convert to int.

Answer (score 0):

I am using AngularJS (V1) I fixed same issue for myself by adding a simple filter like:

```
filter('stringToNumber', function(){
    return function (input) {
    if (!input)
        return null;

    return Number(input)
};
});
```

**Using this:**

```
price: stringToNumber(price);
```